# Column sum with matrix from txt file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I've been given a matrix that I have to put into a text file, and take the sum of one of the columns (from a command line)

So the program I have to make has to take the matrix txt file and the column number as two command line arguments.

I'm very inexperienced with matrices and accessing txt.files (we've barely touched upon it in class)

What I have so far :

```
import numpy
import sys

txtfile = sys.argv[1]
columnsum = sys.argv[2]

a = [2,16,-3,9]
b = [4,5,2,0]
c = [5,2,3,11]
d = [6,-2,-3,4]

m1 = numpy.array(a)
m2 = numpy.array(b)
m3 = numpy.array(c)
m4 = numpy.array(d)

numpy.savetxt('matrixp4.txt',(m1,m2,m3,m4),fmt="%d")
```

In the editor I'm using (pycharm), the matrix seems to be secure in the txt file, but when I run it, it says there's a syntax error in the first line of the matrix. I'm very stuck, I just don't know matrices very well. Any help? Did I format the matrix wrong?

Comment: I don't understand... in the text, you say that you have to read the matrix, but in the code you are writing the matrix...

Comment: Is there another way to put the matrix in a text file? It wasn't given to me as a text file. I don't know how else to put it in a text file other than this...

Comment: Works for me, what's the syntax error you get? You could write to file with the csv module https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html or simply f = open('file.txt','wb') then f.write(data)

Comment: Yeah I think it's okay in the text file, but now i'm stuck on how its supposed to "read" the file and sum the column.

Comment: @Jon, you should split up the write and read operations into separate scripts or functions.  you don't want to re-write the file every time you read it.

Comment: and why don't you do some googling to see how one would load a numpy matrix that has been saved in a text file using `savetxt`.  when you get stuck on something basic like this, your first action shouldn't be to post a question to SO.

Comment: and why not make your matrix a 2D numpy `array`, as opposed to a tuple of 1D arrays?  (again, how to do this can be found easily from a google search.)

Comment: First, if you have an error in the reading function, please include that code.  Second, please edit the question to include the complete error.  Third, do you want an array or a matrix?  You say matrix, but work with arrays.  These are not the same thing.  Fourth, did you not get any guidance at all on what format the text file should have?